# Older sci-fi novel: Girl meets stranded time traveller/wizard

Tags: story-identification, novel

I checked out a book from the library a few years back, and it seemed like it wasn't very recently published at the time. I'm guessing it was published sometime between 1980 and 2005. Huge gap, I know. I can't remember the title, author, or any of the characters' names. Here are the details I know:

- There are two main characters. A (teenage?) girl and a man.
- The setting is somewhere in Britain or Australia, because I distinctly remember the girl referring to her mom as "mum".
- The girl is bored with her life and feels that there is something more out there, or whatever
- The man is some guy from the future and outer space who got stuck in the girl's time (the present). And he ends up taking shelter in the woods behind the girls house.
- The guy is a wizard or something too, I think. I know that there was a lot of magic involved in this book as well.
- Of course they meet, and through a series of events, the reader later finds out that the characters knew each other in an alternate universe or future or past life or something. The girl used to live and work on a futuristic space ship or space colony or something.

The plot was really complicated and weird, so this might not be a good recall of the actual plot. But if you have any clue of what I'm talking about, please help!

Comment: I know you've put in a lot of detail, but it's still quite vague, if the over all plot is hard to recall, are there any specific scenes that stick in your mind from the story?

Comment: Or, a surprisingly helpful thing -- do you remember what the cover looked like?  Style / characters / action / etc?

Comment: I don't think I can come up with anything else lol. This is so frustrating! But I want to say that the cover had a girl on the front who is in a ship (maybe a jumpsuit and shorter hair?) sitting at controls. I think.

Answer (score 14):

Could this be "[Hexwood](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0064473554)" by Diana Wynne Jones? Published in 1993, it is set in England and has a teenage girl and mysterious man in woods (wizard), a convoluted plot, and  alternate universes/identities/timelines.

Comment: Please explain why you'd believe this to be the case.

Comment: Sorry! Published in 1993; the setting is in England; teenage girl and mysterious man in woods (wizard); convoluted plot; alternate universes/identities/timelines.

Comment: @Frock — Don't be sorry.

Comment: It is worth adding that the girl and the man did know each other and had worked together on another planet as it happens. The way they know each other is very particular to the book (magically the world isn't the way they think it is). He has powers you might describe as magical and there is a lot of magic in it. He isn't from the future, though he is from off planet (as of course is she), but time is somewhat confused as well.